# Las palabras definidas como género ambiguo como "internet" ¿se deben utilizar con artículo femenino o masculino?

Tags: género

Para el caso de la palabra "internet", tenía un profesor en preparatoria que comentaba que debería ser "la internet" puesto que "internet" es "la red de redes". Sin embargo aquí en México cuando decimos internet decimos "el internet".

Según la RAE internet es "nombre ambiguo":

> [internet](http://dle.rae.es/internet).
>
> 1. **amb**. Red informática mundial, descentralizada, formada por la conexión directa entre computadoras mediante un protocolo especial de comunicación.
>
> ORTOGR. Escr. t. con may. inicial.

- Este tipo de palabras con género ambiguo, ¿con qué género de artículo (masculino o femenino) deben usarse?
- ¿Existen otras palabras como "internet" con género ambiguo?

Comment: Si pones el ratón encima de "**amb.**" verás un texto que dice "nombre ambiguo".

Comment: Las palabras en ese caso son polisémicas, lo que quiere decir que tienen la misma morfología pero no la misma semántica (similar, aunque para nada igual a la palabras homófonas). En el caso de las palabras que pueden tener ambos géneros serían las siguientes: calor, azúcar, mar, etc. No cambian de significado a pesar del cambio de género.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Un [nombre ambiguo](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=ambiguo&val_aux=&origen=REDRAE) es aquél que [puede ser usado en másculino o en femenino](http://blog.lengua-e.com/2007/nombres-ambiguos-en-cuanto-al-genero/) y su significado no cambia:

> Los nombres ambiguos en cuanto al género son aquellos que se pueden utilizar tanto en masculino como en femenino sin que cambie su significado. Algunos ejemplos son *mar, maratón, linde, dracma y azúcar*.

En el caso de Internet, por ejemplo, además de poder usarse la Internet o el Internet, en España al menos es muy usual verlo u oírlo como "Internet" sin artículo, aunque se usa en masculino: "Internet es muy amplio". Otros, como tu profesor, prefieren el femenino: "la Internet es muy amplia".

Por tanto, la respuesta a sobre qué género usar en los sustantivos ambiguos es que ambos géneros están permitidos. Generalmente suele haber preferencias en cada palabra según el uso, tradición o área.

Hay otros nombres ambiguos como los que se dan en el ejemplo: mar, maratón, linde, dracma y azúcar:

- El mar o la mar.
- El maratón o la maratón.
- El linde o la linde.
- El dracma o la dracma.
- El azúcar o la azúcar.

Como ya he dicho antes, el uso de uno u otra género puede depender de cómo se haya usado tradicionalmente en una zona (caso de Internet), o del contexto en el que se use ("mar" en contextos marinos suele emplearse en femenino).

Sobre azúcar, [puedes leer aquí](http://blog.lengua-e.com/2007/azucar-un-caso-especial-de-nombre-ambiguo-en-cuanto-al-genero/) algunos comentarios muy interesantes al respecto:

> Lo que hace especial a azúcar en comparación con otros nombres
>   ambiguos en cuanto al género es que se combina con el artículo
>   masculino también cuando se usa en femenino: 
>   *Los propios industriales refresqueros han devaluado **el azúcar refinada**
>   en 15 y 20 por ciento.*

No son nombres ambiguos los que al cambiar el género cambia también su sinificado: "el cólera" y "la cólera" son cosas distintas.

Answer (score 5):

Yo diría que se usa como si fuera un nombre propio, así que lo correcto es usarlo **sin artículo** y con la inicial en mayúscula.

Sería igual de incorrecto decir *"el Internet"* o *"la Internet"* que decir *"la Carmen"* o *"el Juan"*.

**Edito para incluir fuente:**

http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=internet

> Funciona a modo de nombre propio, por lo que, en el uso mayoritario
>   de todo el ámbito hispánico, se escribe con mayúscula inicial y sin
>   artículo

Comment: La RAE tan solo menciona que la mayoría lo usa sin artículo, pero no dice que sea incorrecto poner artículo.

Comment: La RAE solo recoge el uso que se hace del idioma, no dicta cómo debe usarse.

Comment: Entonces entonces es correcto usarlo con artículo, porque es el uso que se le da.

Comment: @cgc +1 por la liga a la RAE, de hecho explica lo que mi profesor decía respecto a el porqué algunos prefieren llamarla "la Internet".

Answer (score 4):

En mi muy personal punto de vista, el que más te guste es correcto. Conozco mucha gente de distintos países de habla hispana, y cada quien usa el género que mejor le parece y, en algunos casos, incluso gente del mismo país, algunos lo usan como masculino y otros como femenino.

Otro ejemplo de este caso es el de "computer" (lo escribo en inglés precisamente por la ambigüedad del español).

En algunos lugares dicen "el computador" y en otros "la computadora".

Comment: Estuve pensando este, pero no estuve seguro. ¿Es "mar" una otra palabra que es ambiguo?

Comment: @Luke - Interesante, creo que tienes razón y también puede ser un término ambigüo. Sin embargo creo, y esa es solo mi opinión, que es más común decir "el mar", "la mar" se usa más bien en canciones y poesías.

Comment: @American Luke Oddly enough, jrdioko posted that same question.  The link to it is here: [**What are the differences between “el mar” and “la mar”?**](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/what-are-the-differences-between-el-mar-and-la-mar)  HTH.